# Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

When i was run my spring boot application i have facing the following errors.anyone can face it please help me.and the following are the posted my application.yml.

Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'characterEncodingFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter]: Factory method 'characterEncodingFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.setForceRequestEncoding(Z)V
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

```
application.yml
    server:
      port: 8080
      context-path: /crudapp
    spring:
      profiles: local,default
      datasource:
        sampleapp:
        url:  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/employee
        username: root
        password: root
        driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        schema:
        - defaultSchema:
          maximum-pool-size: 10
          hibernate:
          hbm2ddl.method: update
          dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
          show_sql: true
          format_sql: true
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>registration</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>registration</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency> -->
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.jappyframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>jappy-framework</artifactId>
    <version>5.7.19</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<!--    <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.5</version>
</dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6582

Comment: `MethodNotFoundException` is *always* version mismatch issue. Welcome to Java 101

Comment: ok..but here i am using latest version of all jars....

Comment: Thx, update the version of the dependencies  solved my problem.